# mysql get conditional value from mysql select?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

So say I have a table called users with the following values: ip, id, and user. If I want to get all the users based on ip, but don't have the ip, then I would do first `select ip from users where user = "user";` and afterwards, `select user from users where ip = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx[x]";` (the x's being the ip numbers gotten from the first query). Is there not a way to do something like `select user from users where ip = "[insert ip query here to get ip]"` where the whole thing is compacted in 1 query? I know this may sound silly over 2 statements, but every cpu cycle counts for my program especially on a rather slow platform.

Comment: Can you post the database schema & some sample data? Not quite clear what you are asking.

Comment: Basically, if I have a condition `WHERE value = key`, is there a way to get the `key` from its own query that's within the `WHERE` clause.

`select ip from users where user = "key";`
`select user from users where user = "[value from query]";`

would become `select user from users where ip = "[insert first query here in code to get key value]";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly a question for the query you're looking for is *Find me all users who share the same ip as userX*. If it is the case then you can do it either with `JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.user 
  FROM users u1 JOIN users u2
    ON u1.ip = u2.ip
 WHERE u2.user = 'some_user';
```

or with a subquery

```
SELECT user 
  FROM users
 WHERE ip IN
 (
     SELECT DISTINCT ip
       FROM users
      WHERE user = 'some_user'
 );
```

or with `EXISTS`

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user 
  FROM users u 
 WHERE EXISTS
 (
     SELECT *
       FROM users
      WHERE ip = u.ip
      AND user = 'some_user'
 );
```

Note: make sure that you have indices on `ip` and `user`.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea1297/4)** demo

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing the same query twice, the following example shows a nested select, it it an incredibly redundant example but It shows what you want (I think)

```
SELECT user FROM users 
WHERE user = (SELECT user FROM users 
              WHERE ip = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx[x]");
```

In this query the subquery will actually return the same as the outer query so it's pointless.

Answer (score -1):

i guess that u can use subquery like this:
select user from USERS where ip in(select ip from USERS where user like "%user%")

Comment: That is actually a comment, if you do not have enough popularity to post a comment it means you are not expected to post a comment, please respect the system